# combining two sql rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: desired output image][image: data tabel]
In the data tabel when the PRICE_TYPE = MSRP, the amount  should be added to column msrp  and when PRICE_TYPE = SELP the amount should be added selp column,
How can i write a query to get the above task done , thanks in advance.
 the first image should be the desired output.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Try searching if else in select query in Sql server.

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: i have added the resulting output image to the question ...please have a look at it

Comment: @dinithjayabodhi I edit my answer you can try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to get your expected result:

```
select  MATERIAL_NUMBER, [MSRP],[SELP] 
FROM
    (
     SELECT 
          MATERIAL_NUMBER,
          PriceType,
          Sum(Amount)
     FROM Org_table
     GROUP BY  
          MATERIAL_NUMBER,
          PriceType
    ) tbl
    pivot 
    (
     sum(Amount) 
     for PriceType in ([MSRP],[SELP])
    )
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem like want to get pivot, you can try to use condition aggregate function.

`CASE WHEN` with aggregate function.

```
SELECT MATERIAL_NUMBER,
       SUM(CASE WHEN  PRICE_TYPE = 'MSRP' THEN AMOUNT END ) MSRP, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN  PRICE_TYPE = 'SELP' THEN AMOUNT END ) SELP
FROM T
GROUP BY  
        MATERIAL_NUMBER
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=190f3ee86498bafb1194502933691e70)

**NOTE**

because your `Amount` seem like a float value, some I use `SUM`